# How to solve latency issue in quiz application?

Tags: android, kotlin, latency

I have array with more elements than posted here. I show only 2 in post but there are 10 `showGreen` variables, 10 additional threads, 10 "TextViews" and 10 `isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear` functions. As you see, when answer is correct, `TextView1` or `TextView2` becomes green on `ACTION_DOWN` and sets random image in `image_view` thus preparing next question. The problem is that if I use 10 threads which separately set value of answer for every `TextView` every 500ms, if user press correct answer `TextView` too fast, it will be treated as wrong answer (red). If I set from 500ms to 300ms or less, sometimes `showGreen` never gets updated correctly. Do you maybe know any solution for my problem?

```
    class Cats : AppCompatActivity() {

                var cats = intArrayOf(
                    R.drawable.cat1,
                    R.drawable.cat2,
                    R.drawable.cat3,
                    R.drawable.cat4,
                    R.drawable.cat5,
                    R.drawable.cat6,
                    R.drawable.cat7,
                    R.drawable.cat8,
                    R.drawable.cat9,
                    R.drawable.cat10,
                    R.drawable.cat11,
                    R.drawable.cat12,
                    R.drawable.cat13,
                    R.drawable.cat14,
                    R.drawable.cat15,
                    R.drawable.cat16,
                    R.drawable.cat17
                )

                lateinit var random: Random

                var showGreen1 = false
                var showGreen2 = false

                val runnable1 = Runnable {
                    while (true) {
                        showGreen1 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear1()
                        Thread.sleep(500)
                    }
                }
                val runnable2 = Runnable {
                    while (true) {
                        showGreen2 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear2()
                        Thread.sleep(500)
                    }
                }
                 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

                      random = Random()
                    Thread(runnable1).start()
                Thread(runnable2).start()

                TextView1.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                            when (motionEvent.action) {

                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                    if (showGreen1) {
                                        TextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
                                image_view.setImageResource(cats[random.nextInt(cats.size)])
/*showGreen1 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear1()
showGreen2 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear2()*/
                                    } else {
                                        TextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

                                    }
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                    TextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)
                                }


                            }
                            return@OnTouchListener true
                        })

                        TextView2.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                            when (motionEvent.action) {

                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                    if (showGreen2) {
                                        TextView2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
                                        image_view.setImageResource(cats[random.nextInt(cats.size)])
                                    } else {
                                        TextView2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

                                    }
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                                    TextView2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)
                                }


                            }
                            return@OnTouchListener true
                        })
            /*while(true)
            {
            showGreen1 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear1()

            showGreen2 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear2()

            }*/




                        fun isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear1(): Boolean {
                    return image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat1
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat2
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat3
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat4
                    )?.constantState ||


                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat5
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat6
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat7
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat8
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat9
                    )?.constantState
                }



                fun isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear2(): Boolean {
                    return image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat10
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat11
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat12
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat13
                    )?.constantState ||


                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat14
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat15
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat16
                    )?.constantState ||
                            image_view.drawable.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        this,
                        R.drawable.cat17
                    )?.constantState
                }
    }
```

Comment: Using threads may be adding to the problem rather than solving it. When threads are used, any access to shared data and UI elements must be coordinated so that all threads are seeing the same states over time. A common bug using threads is stale data which may appear as latency. There may also be delayed initialization occurring here but it's harder to see with the threads.

I suggest running code in event handlers that change the question/answer states all on the main thread (e.g. not creating extra threads).

Comment: Look at my comments in the code where I tried to place event handlers instead of creating new threads and putting them there. If I do like this, my activity totally crashes (black screen). If I put `Thread.sleep(1000)` after event handlers, it gives the same result.

Comment: If I use that code in one additional thread, it has extremely high latency.

Comment: My suggestion was to learn how to use event handlers, without any `Thread` in your code and no `sleep`s. The basic logic is inside some `onSomeEventHandler` code that you: (1) check the current state variable value; (2) change that state variable value; and (3) make the display changes to match the new state variable value.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean. Actually with one `Thread` checking works fine, just high latency. But with 10 threads sometimes variables doesn't get updated at all. I don't understand why do I get black screen when I use code in the main thread. However, my main problem is latency. Checking current state takes very long time.

Comment: What is the effect of `showGreen1 = isGreenBackgroundShouldAppear1()` as seen by the user? I was asking if this logic could also be done in event handlers or is it some sort of animation/transition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205093/discussion-between-prako2-and-karmakaze).