# How to apply random list of numbers for selection from array to select image?

Tags: android, arrays, list, kotlin, random

How to make list of random numbers and use it to set image from array?

```
val randomValues = List(15) { Random.nextInt(0, 5) }
var array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5)
imageView.setImageResource(array[randomValues])
```

I'm getting Type mismatch on `randomValues` in  `imageView.setImageResource(array[randomValues])`. `Required: Int and Found: List <int>`.

### Edited

```
val randomValues = List(15) { Random.nextInt(0, 5) }
        var array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5)


        imageView.setOnClickListener {
            randomValues
                .map { array[it] }
                .forEach { imageView.setImageResource(it) }
        }
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to do? If you want to select a random image from the array you don't need the list, but only a single number: `imageView.setImageResource(array[Random.nextInt(0, 5)])`.

Comment: No, I don't want it to be random. I want to use from pre-created list by specific order like from [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select a new random image at each click you just need to do:

```
val array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1, R.drawable.cat2, R.drawable.cat3, R.drawable.cat4, R.drawable.cat5)


imageView.setOnClickListener {
    imageView.setImageResource(array.random())
}
```

If you absolutely need to use a predefined list of random values (what's the point?), then you need to track the last index you used. Something like:

```
// in your class
var lastIndex = 0
val randomValues = List(15) { Random.nextInt(0, 5) }

// setting the listener
val array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1, R.drawable.cat2, R.drawable.cat3, R.drawable.cat4, R.drawable.cat5)

imageView.setOnClickListener {
    imageView.setImageResource(array[randomValues[lastIndex]])
    lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % randomValues.size
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not actually what I want. As I see, you use quantity of elements of `randomValues` but actually elements from array are selected by order (they are not randomly created). "what's the point?" - See linked post. I have latency problem with checking images, so I want to pre-create random list and check that list to get all right answers. I would really appreciate if you know I way how to solve that problem.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. I corrected the code from  `array[lastIndex]` to `array[randomValues[lastIndex]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to select simply a random element from the array, you can use the `Array.random()` method which just *returns a random element from the array*:

```
var array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5)
imageView.setImageResource(array.random())
```

**Edit**

If you want to select a list of resources based on a randomly generated list of indices, you can achieve this by transforming every index into the right resource. Then you can perform your action on every selected item using the `forEach` method:

```
var array = intArrayOf(R.drawable.cat1,R.drawable.cat2,R.drawable.cat3,R.drawable.cat4,R.drawable.cat5)
val randomValues = List(15) { Random.nextInt(0, 5) }

randomValues
    .map { array[it] }
    .forEach { imageView.setImageResource(it) }
```

Basically your approach failed because you tried to use the entire `randomValues` list as a single index value. Instead you should iterate over the list in one way or another and select the resource for each randomly generated number.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to create list before, and use by order of that list. For example, if list is `1,3,9,7`and I use it in `setOnClickListener()`, on every click it should give me images by order `1,3,9,7`.

Comment: If you're curious why I want to do this, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523159/how-to-solve-latency-issue-in-quiz-application). My goal is to set values for questions before quiz.

Comment: @vasik988 `ImageView.setImageResource()` takes only one argument, do you have more than one `ImageView` or would like to use a single one and replace every image with a new one according to the list of indices?

Comment: Replace every image with a new one according to the list of indices

Comment: Ok, but I don't really understand how to use `randomValues
    .map { array[it] }
    .forEach { imageView.setImageResource(it) }` in `setOnClickListener()`. If I press on imageView, nothing changes.

Comment: @vasik988 Putting the above code into `setOnClickListener` either as a lambda or a separate function should do the work. The problem might be however, that all the changes are applied faster than the UI is able to respond and in the end only the last transition will be noticeable. Given the fact you have only 5 possibilities, it may occur that the last drawable is the same as the first one quite often, so it appears like nothing has happened. I assumed you have already figured how to handle this problem as that hasn't seem like your concern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205077/discussion-between-vasik988-and-jsamol).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205114/discussion-between-prako2-and-jsamol).